# How does a single point load cell eliminate the inluence of moment/load placement

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, moments, force-measurement

All descriptions I have been able to find mention some variation of "due to their geometrical design single point load cells are immune to load placement" with no explanation on how is it achieved. How does the geometry separate the perpendicular load measured from the moment caused by its' placement?

[image: Single point load cell illustration]

Comment: Usually the rigid platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the cut out in the middle? That turns it into a 4 bar linkage. Moments are reacted by opposing strains in the upper and lower arms. The strain gages are crosswired so that moments produce a cancelling effect whereas vertical loads add.